# Django REST Framework: how to dynamically change a field name when inheriting

Tags: python, oop, django-rest-framework

I want to create a base class that will be used by other classes. Only one field name will change depending on the child class.

```py
class Person(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    other_fields = ...

    def validate(self, attrs):
        # something to validate the name and other fields together
        ...
```

```py
class John(Person):
    john_name = Person.name # ?
```

All I want is to be able to receive a payload like this: `{"john_name": "john"}`, without the need to redo the `Person` validations for every child class of `Person` that the code needs.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking for?

```py
class John(Person):
    john_name = serializer.charField(write_only=True)

    def create(self,validated_data):
      person_name = validated_data.pop('john_name')
      validated_data["person_name"] = person_name
      return Super().create(validated_data)
```